# How to assign filters to row number () function in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to extract only single row after name = system in each case where the town is not Austin.
In case 1001 there are 8 rows, row # 4 is system, output should be only the row with Name=Terry and Date Moved=7/4/2019 (Next entry with town /= Austin)

```
Case    Name      Town            Date Moved         Row #(Not in table)
1001    Ted       Madisson         9/7/2018            1
1001    Joyal     Boston           10/4/2018           2
1001    Beatrice  Chicago          1/1/2019            3
1001    System    Chicago          1/5/2019            4
1001    John      Austin           4/11/2019           5
1001    Simon     Austin           6/11/2019           6
1001    Terry     Cleveland        7/4/2019            7
1001    Hawkins   Newyork          8/4/2019            8
1002    Devon     Boston           12/4/2018           1
1002    Joy       Austin           12/7/2018           2
1002    Rachael   Newyork          12/19/2018          3
1002    Bill      Chicago          1/4/2019            4
1002    System    Dallas           2/12/2019           5
1002    Phil      Austin           3/16/2019           6
1002    Dan       Seattle          5/18/2019           7
1002    Claire    Birmingham       7/7/2019            8
```

Tried sub query with row number function and not in ('Austin') filter

ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Case ORDER BY Moved_date ASC) AS ROWNUM

Please note there are > 10k cases.

Comment: If you could provide your complete query that would be helpful.

Comment: with Name as 
(
select 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Case ORDER BY moved_date ASC) AS rownum
,name
,moved_date
from Movements
where
case in (
'1001',
'1002'
)
and city not in ('Austin')

)
select name.*
where rownum > (select rownum
from name.*
where city = 'Austin'
)

Comment: Can this happen more than once per case?

Comment: No, only once per case. Since there are around 15k cases, with each case over 100 rows. Also the row # is just an illustration, its not part of the actual table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three possibilities. I'm still concerned about ties though. The first one will return multiple rows while the others only one per case:

```
with matches as (
    select t1."case", min(t2."Date Moved") as "Date Moved"
    from Movements r1 inner join Movements t2 on t1."case" = t2."case"
    where t1.name = 'System' and t2.Town <> 'Austin'
        and t2."Date Moved" > t1."Date Moved"
    group by t1."case"
)
select t.*
from Movements t inner join matches m
    on m."case" = t."case" and m."Date Moved" = t."Date Moved";

select m2.*
from Movements m1 cross apply (
    select top 1 * from Movements m2
    where m2.Town <> 'Austin' and m2."Date Moved" > m1."Date Moved"
    order by m2."Date Moved"
) as match
where m1.name = 'System';

with m1 as (
    select *,
        count(case when name = 'System') over (partition by "case" order by "Date Moved") as flag
    from Movements
), m2 as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by "case" order by "Date Moved") as rn
    from m1
    where flag = 1 and name <> 'System' and Town <> 'Austin'
)
select * from m2 where rn = 1;
```

I'm basically assuming this is SQL Server. You might need a few minor tweaks if not.

It also does not require a town named Austin to fall between the "System" row and the desired row as I do not believe that was a stated requirement.

Comment: Sorry about this, Row # column was just an illustration. Its not part of the table.

Comment: @user1731466 You'll still be able to compare by date then. Can two rows have the same date?

Comment: Yea, very much. Most of the rows have same dates

Comment: How will you break ties between them?

Comment: If the date of the corresponding row >= date of the row with system

Comment: @user1731466 You just said most have the same date. Hopefully these actually have a time component so there's really nothing to worry about anyway. Have you given these a try?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below script-

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT [Case],[Name],Town,[Date Moved],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Case] ORDER BY [Date Moved])  [Row #]
    FROM your_table
)


SELECT A.* 
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT C.[Case],C.Town,MAX(C.[Row #]) MRN
    FROM CTE C
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM CTE A  
        WHERE  A.Name = 'System'
    )D ON C.[Case] = D.[Case] AND C.[Row #] > D.[Row #]
    AND C.Town = 'Austin'
    GROUP BY C.[Case],C.Town
)B ON A.[Case] = B.[Case] AND A.[Row #] = B.MRN+1
```

Output is -

```
Case    Name    Town        Date Moved  Row #
1001    Terry   Cleveland   7/4/2019    6
1002    Dan     Seattle     5/18/2019   7
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I am trying to input the [Case] numbers. where can i add this filter

Comment: Do you mean filtering by  case like "WHERE [case] = 1001"? You can add this condition Inside CTE selection.